# Making a font-icon a file upload button

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

How would I go about making a font-awesome icon like the faCamera accept fileUpload, basically make the font awesome icon into an input div with type file. Ive placeholder on the input div but it doesnt really work.

What I have

```
        <input placeHolder={faImage} type='file' accept="image/*" onChange={handleFileSelect}</input>
        <FontAwesomeIcon type="file" icon={faImage}></FontAwesomeIcon>
```